# PostgreSQL "pg_prewarm" buffer size

Tags: postgresql

Table `orders` contains total 1,500,000 toples. After a fresh restart of the system, I ran the following query:

`SELECT pg_prewarm('orders');
EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) SELECT * FROM orders WHERE o_totalprice < 100`

Which gave a buffer output as following:

`Buffers: shared hit=15768 read=10327`

The select statement returns no records.

Now my question is, how did PostgreSQL calculate that it will take 15768 blocks in buffer?

Comment: "will take"  It didn't.  It actually did it and counted, it is not a prediction.

Answer (score 2):

Your `shared_buffers` is set to 128MB, right?

128 MB of shared buffers translates to 16384 blocks of size 8KB in the cache.

So when you run `pg_prewarm('orders')`, PostgreSQL will read the complete table into shared buffers. Now the table is bigger than your `shared_buffers`, so the first blocks “drop out” of the cache again when the last blocks are read, because `shared_buffers` cannot fit them all.

Increase `shared_buffers` if you want to have the whole table in the cache.

Comment: is it possible to pull data conditionally into shared_buffers? For example something like
SELECT pg_prewarm('orders') where WHERE o_totalprice < 100;

Comment: No. But I'd say you should simply leave caching to PostgreSQL's algorithm - it will cache the frequently used data automatically. Rather than trying to micro-manage the cache, increase it; that will probably make most problems go away.